# Connect two laptops through wi-fi

Tags: 14.04, wireless

I want to connect 2 laptops using wi-fi. I don't want to share internet using this connection instead I want to test my programs which use sockets and are run on 2 machines.
When I connected the 2 systems through an ethernet cable, both of them got a private IP address(eg 192.168.1.100). I want to do something similar to this using wi-fi. Is it possible?

Answer (score 2):

I think what you want is 'ad-hoc'. You can create an ad-hoc network on one device, and connect to this network from the other device. I am assuming both devices have Ubuntu installed; you can follow this steps:

Click the network connections indicator in the upper right corner at your screen:

[image: network connections indicator]

Choose **Edit Connections...** and click the **Add** button at the right in the window opened:

[image: add a new network connection]

Then select **Wi-Fi** as the connection type, then press the button **Create...**.

[image: create a new Wi-Fi connection]

Then in the opened window, set the details as you wish, only thing you have to modify is the **SSID**, it is the name of the wireless network.

**Make sure you selected the Mode as the Ad-hoc.**

[image: create an ad-hoc moded network connection]

When you press save the connection will be saved and in a few seconds you should be able connect the other device to the network, too.

Comment: What if I have ubuntu on 1 system and windows on another or the other is an android device. Would this work? I tried doing this with an android device, the device is unable to discover the connection.

Comment: Android can't connect to ad-hoc (some say it can after rooting and some modifications but i am not sure), however, windows should work.